# Using 'loadkeys' to load Programmers Dvorak on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, dvorak

I am in the process of setting up a virtual server and need to know how to switch the servers keyboard layout to Programmers Dvorak since that is what I am use to.

I am currently using

```
sudo loadkeys dvorak
```

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: This is more of an OS configuration question (rather than a programmers tools question), and would probably be a better fit at [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your command:

```
sudo loadkeys dvorak
```

Gives a standard dvorak layout. 
If You want the Programmer Dvorak layout you have 2 options:

1. Persistent:
   Set `/etc/default/console-setup` to

   ```
   XKBLAYOUT="us"
   XKBVARIANT="dvp"
   XKBOPTIONS="compose:102,numpad:shift3,kpdl:semi,keypad:atm,caps:shift"
   ```
2. Until next login:

   ```
   setxkbmap -layout us -variant dvp -option compose:102 -option numpad:shift3 -option kpdl:semi -option keypad:atm -option caps:shift
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to switch layouts myself, probably because the few Linux installs I've done I went with the option that lets you pick the system layout during the setup (maybe server doesn't have that option?).  Still, the way you are doing it is probably the best way for temporarily switching.  If you are looking to change it system-wide, I would suggest you try using this method ([detailed here](http://krisreeves.com/things-that-should-be-easy/permanently-change-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-server-11-10)).

You need to edit `/etc/default/keyboard`. After that, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` to commit your settings.

When you run console-setup, it compiles in the keyboard layout listed in that file, which is why console-data’s changes were not kept. In the file are four lines:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

To get the Dvorak layout, add `dvorak` as the XKBVARIANT value before running console-setup.